# How to make a java app for symbian platform?

Tags: java, symbian

Sorry but i am a noob.
please tell me what is wrong if i make a jar file of my java class and it runs perfectly on my pc but it wont work on my symbian S60 version 5 mobile.

please tell me the difference for writing code for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download and install the AppTRK application from Carbide onto your phone, and connect the phone to your PC via USB, you may get some debug traces that help you.

This works for native apps, I'm not sure if it'll work for Java ones

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no one can tell you exactly why certain code works in some conditions and fails in other. You have to use a debugger to find out which portions of code cause the trouble and why. You haven't said which phone you use, but I believe you may start with the [Nokia Developer's site for Java](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/).